# Angular material selection list with add functionality

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to use an angular selection list, but additionally, I'd like the user to be able to add new items to the list. If he has already selected a few, this selection should not get lost.

Usually, I'd add a method in the component to add the element to the data list, and then recreate the `MatSelectionList` I am binding to the view. But then the current selection is lost.

I've tried variations of this in the component (beware, it's pseudo-code):

```
@ViewChild("items", { static: true }) items: ElementRef;

addItem(item: Item): void {
    var selectionList = <MatSelectionList><unknown>this.items
    
    // Hoped to find something like: 
    // selectionList.options.add(...):

    // or recreate the source, and remembering the selection: 
    // let selected = selectionList.selectedOptions.selected.map(s => s.value);
    // this.items = new MatSelectionList(this._originalItems.push(newItem))
    // this.items.selectedOptions.setSelected(...)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Selection List Example](https://material.angular.io/components/list/examples), you would be able to do this (not tested) :

```html
<input placeholder="Enter new item" [(ngModel)]="newItem" />
<button (click)="addItem()">Add</button>

<mat-selection-list #shoes>
  <mat-list-option *ngFor="let shoe of typesOfShoes">
    {{shoe}}
  </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>

<p>
  Options selected: {{shoes.selectedOptions.selected.length}}
</p>
```

```
newItem: string;
typesOfShoes: string[] = ['Boots', 'Clogs', 'Loafers', 'Moccasins', 'Sneakers'];

addItem(): void {
  this.typesOfShoes.push(this.newItem);
}
```

Comment: Omg, so simple, and it works, thank you. I remembered that for material tables you have to recreate the dataSource, so I didn't even try this direct approach.